# git cherry-pick weird issue, sometimes conflicts but sometimes not

Tags: git

Let's say we have below history:

```
     master->m2   s2<-second
             |     |
             m1   s1
               \ /
                a0
```

so `a0` is the initial commit that has a text file called `letter.txt` that contain a letter `a`, each commit on the master branch append the next alphabet, so the `letter.txt` in `m1` contains `ab` and `m2` contains `abc`, then I checkout the second branch and on I add a new file let's say `bugfixcode.cs`, so `s1` and `s2` are all in regards to add/modify `bugfixcode.cs`, then I switch back to **master**, and find I want to cherry-pick some commit from second branch, here is something weird:

Q1. if I cherry-pick s2, then it will be a conflict, but if I cherry-pick s1, then no conflict.
For the conflict when cherry-picking `s2`, I think it is because the content of `letter.txt` on the second branch is still `a`, but the file on `m2` has `abc`, but isn't that the same fact on `s1`? why there is no conflict on `s1`

Q2. For the conflict when cherry-picking `s2`, why there is no conflict marker like `<<<<<<< HEAD` in `letter.txt`? if there is no conflict marker , then there is no conflicts, isn't it?

Comment: You should not get conflicts for files that are not changed in the commit you are cherry-picking from. Check `git show --stat s2` to confirm whether it touches the file `letter.txt`.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe this in words, please give an actual series of git commands that would allow us to replicate the scenario.

Comment: Also why do you think the conflict is about letter.txt? It seems to me that it’s about the other file.

Comment: @matt  how come it is the other file? it doesn't even exist on master branch

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with *letter.txt*. It's about *bugfixcode.cs*.

What's a cherry-pick? It is a merge performed as if the *parent* of the target commit (the commit named at the end of the `cherry-pick` command) were the ancestor of both commits (the target commit and the commit we are cherry-picking onto, i.e. `HEAD`).

To put it another way, it is a replay (onto `HEAD`) of the diff (the patch) that gets you from the target commit's parent to the target commit.

So you've got this:

```
--- A has no file x
\
 \--- B creates file x --- C modifies file x
```

So now you try to cherry-pick C onto A. That means: replay the B-to-C diff on top of A. You are saying: "Please do to me, A, what you did to B in order to get C."

Well, what *did* you do to B in order to get C? What *is* the difference between B and C? It's the *modification of file x*. But in A there is *no* file x at all! So what on earth does *that* mean? How can we, starting with A, modify a file that isn't even there? Git has no idea, so it throws up its hands.

(The same problem doesn't exist if you cherry-pick B onto A, because it is obvious what the diff is there: create the file.)

To see this in a controlled way, just play out the scenario. Keep your eye on the file that I call *file2*:

```
git init
echo "howdy" > file
git add .
git commit -m "start"

git branch mybranch
git checkout mybranch
echo "test" > file2
git add .
git commit -m "created file2"
echo "test" >> file2
git add .
git commit -m "modified file2"

git checkout master
git cherry-pick a5d16cb4
```

What do we get? A conflict. And the error message tells us clearly what it is:

```
error: could not apply a5d16cb... modified file2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Read the words. The problem is that C "modified file2". And the proposed solution is to `add` or `rm` the problematic file, *file2*.

Another way to see what the problem is, is to do at that point a `git status`. Here's what we get:

```
On branch master
You are currently cherry-picking commit a5d16cb.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by us:   file2
```

Again, we are told that the issue is *file2* and that the solution is to `add` or `rm` it. The phrase "deleted by us" is actually quite useful, and you can use it to express the problem in a possibly better way. Remember, we are trying to merge the diff B-to-A with the diff B-to-C. So, relative to B, which already *has* the file, A *removes* the file, while C *modifies* it. You cannot do both — that's the conflict.

So it's the file created and then modified on your `second` branch that's the issue. And that is why you see no conflict in the file created and modified on `master`; it *isn't* the conflict.