# git rebase on master gives conflict but "plain" merge to master does NOT

Tags: git

When I rebase my branch **my-feature** on **master** I get a conflict:

```
[my-feature]$ git rebase master
Applying: ...
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   vars/file.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging vars/file.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in vars/file.txt
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
```

If I instead do a plain merge of **my-feature** into **master** it works fine:

```
[master] $ git merge my-feature
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
..
```

I have tried to do a fresh clone of my repo to make sure everything is in sync with the remote and in a clean state.

How is it possible that a rebase fails when a plain merge does not?

Been using git for some years now an never seen this before and always assumed that if a merge goes well (no conflicts) its guaranteed that a rebase will as well and vice versa.

Comment: Rebase is using a three way merge. I wonder if that makes a difference?

Comment: A rebase is a cherry-pick. A conflict is more likely with a rebase / cherry-pick because you are pulling a commit out of context and so it is more probable that you are interrupting the history. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848968/341994 for a good example.

Comment: Also please note that you are thinking about this all wrong. A conflict is not a fail! It's just a conflict — Git doesn't know how you want it to proceed automatically so it asks for you to help it. That's good, not bad.

Comment: A conflict is a failure to complete the merge - nothing ends up in master before you actively do something and if I can avoid that extra work by simply doing a merge instead I consider that good. Its not that I get a better/more correct result by doing a rebase + solving a conflict. I might get a prettier history (to some) but functionally there is no difference.

Comment: @matt I agree with your explanation, but I didn't get the impression that OP meant "fail" to be a bad thing. I think the question stemmed from "I thought the result should be the same, but it doesn't appear it always would be." The question aims to pinpoint the cases where the process and result of rebase and merge differ.

Comment: @u123 "functionally there is no difference" between a merge and rebase? Of course there is. They result in completely different history topologies. There are good reasons for preferring one over the other. If you really need a rebase, a rebase is really what you need. :)

Comment: What I mean is if I compile/run my code from the resulting SHA in both cases there will be no differences in the output. But nevermind I understand your point of view just me not getting mine across that well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is it possible that a rebase fails when a plain merge does not?

It doesn't "fail". It has a *conflict*. There is a big difference. A conflict is a form of success — a form of success that requires you to exercise some judgment. That's all it is.

As for how it can be possible to have a conflict during a rebase when you do not have a conflict during a merge, it's because the relative histories of the branches and the way they are being applied are different. If they were the same, a rebase would *be* a merge!

So, for instance, here's a possible scenario:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (master)
     \
      X -- Y (feature)
```

If you **merge** `feature` into `master`, the starting point is B because that is where the histories diverged. Git then takes the whole history B-C-D and the whole history B-X-Y and performs *both* of them on B. It expresses the totality of the result as a new commit, a merge commit, and it makes D and Y the parents of that commit.

If you **rebase** `feature` onto `master`, the starting point is B (again) but for a different reason: it is because that is the parent of the first commit (X) on `feature` that is not in common. Git then completely ignores the history B-C-D; instead, it does *directly to D* whatever was done to get from B to X and makes a commit out of that — and then does to the resulting commit whatever was done to get from X to Y and makes a commit out of *that*. It then moves the name `feature` to point to that last new commit.

Well, it may not be so easy to "do directly to D" what was done to get from B to X. That is why a rebase can be a source of a conflict when a true merge is not.

To put it another way: rebasing here means to *pretend that X grew out of D*. But X did *not* grow out of D; it grew out of B. Things may have happened in C and D that make it hard to grow X out of D instead B.

(To put it still another way: A merge *summarizes* history. A rebase *rewrites* history.)

Comment: I think you put too much weight on the word "fail" as used in the question. That was probably just a bad word choice in the question (the wording of the title is better). I love your last two paragraphs though- nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple causes for this. It usually happens when there's a change made in the middle that creates a conflict (when rebasing) but that a later revision takes back. Merge won't have to deal with the conflicting change because it doesn't care about the middle revisions.... just the tips (and the last common ancestor, roughly) to do the merge.

This is from an edit and I am not 100% sure I agree with it but alas :-):
Another reason this can happen is if your `my-feature` branch contains new merge commits in it. If those merge commits required conflict resolution, then they may need to be resolved again.

Comment: That is only one of many possible reasons.

Comment: There could be other things like files being renamed and changed a lot (therefore git not realizing a rename during a merge) but that's way more unlikely than what I said. But ok, there are other causes.

Comment: No, it's not just that.  There are caess where the merge result isn't even the same as the rebase result.  You can say they're edge cases, but they should not be dismissed.

Comment: Hm interesting so a "plain" merge is more "powerful/robust" that than a rebase? Seems that "if you rebase blows up try an do a plain merge instead" could be a valid statement?

Comment: @eftshift0 please check that you agree with my change to your answer. I incorporated Mark's comment about a merge result sometimes being different from rebase. I'm pretty sure that can only happen if the branch you're rewriting has merge commits in it.

Comment: @u123: I'd put it the other way: the rebase uses more power, and hence can create more messes. :-) (Compare using, e.g., a hand-powered saw vs a table saw. Which one will cut your fingers clean off if you're not careful, and which one will be painful but you'll stop in time to avoid the need for surgical reattachment?)